# Spark hangs after on doing multiple unions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to union a list of `Dataset<Rows>` like so:

```
totalSet = sparkSession.emptyDataset(RowEncoder.apply(schema));
for(var currentDataset : datasetList)
    totalSet = totalSet.union(currentDataset);
totalSet.show(10000,false);
```

There's about 160 datasets in datasetList. totalSet should only have 1k rows at the end of the loop. However, spark gets stuck here in this loop. If I union just 1 dataset from datasetList it works just fine. I thought doing unions ought to be a O(1) operation, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Does anyone know why this code hangs?

Comment: Spark's transformations are lazy and you haven't done any action here to trigger the jobs. So technically, there is no union being done here?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a show operation following the for loop. Added that to the code snippet.